# PHP Date from string

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a specific date format that i need to convert to a normal looking date.

`strtotime()` isnt parsing it correctly.

```
$fulldate = 'Tue Feb 04 2014 09:30:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)';

echo $fulldate.'<br />';
echo strtotime($fulldate).'<br />';
echo date('Y-m-d g:i a', strtotime($fulldate));
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: remove (Pacific Standard Time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a DateTime object:

```
<?php
    $fulldate = 'Tue Feb 04 2014 09:30:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)';
    //remove everything between the brackets
    $dateString = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$fulldate);
    //now, get your date object
    $date = new DateTime($dateString);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Try the Fiddle here: http://ideone.com/odwtUH

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard date format because of the last part (between the brackets).

One idea:

```
$tokens = explode("(", $fulldate);
array_pop($tokens);
$fulldate = trim(join("(", $tokens));
echo strtotime($fulldate);
```

Comment: that worked except the time comes back as 12:30pm??? and it is supposed to be 9:30am

Comment: That's a timezone issue, you may want to check the timezone setting in your php.ini and/or code.

Comment: my timezone is set to America/New_York but i dont understand why that matters.. im taking a date from the database converting it with `strtotime` and then formatting it back with `date()`. shouldnt rely on php.ini settings, should it?

Comment: Yes it does, since strtotime converts the date to a UTC Unix timestamp. date then converts it in a formatted date relative to your default timezone. That's how it works.